# I have fail error: ‘sqlite3_key’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: sqlite, sqlcipher

I have a simple code:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <sqlite.h.in>
#include <cstring> 

int main() {
    sqlite3 *db = nullptr;
    const char *dbName = "en.db";
    const char *key = "encryption_key";

    int result = sqlite3_open(dbName, &db);
    
    result = sqlite3_key(db, key, strlen(key));
    
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}
```

when compile it with:

***g++ encrypt.cpp -o encrypt -Isqlcipher/include -Lsqlcipher/libs -ldl -lsqlciphe***

I have an error:
error: ‘sqlite3_key’ was not declared in this scope

I did verify that libsqlcipher.so has **sqlite3_key**, by running:

***nm libsqlcipher.so | grep sqlite3_key***

and get output:

000000000005b47a T sqlite3_key

000000000005b4cd T sqlite3_key_v2

00000000000dd2e0 T sqlite3_keyword_check

00000000000dd2d1 T sqlite3_keyword_count

00000000000dd260 T sqlite3_keyword_name

it looks as it should like look, but still.
how do I fix that?

and also have verified the path where it located

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC` onto the command used to compile for `sqlite3_key()` to be referenced from the header.